# Torrent Theory?

Tags: c#, sockets

I always wanted to write my own torrent client, but never could find any good info on how to do it. I'm using C# 4.0 right now and I do have some networking skills.

What I really need is a short description of torrent theory, meaning an explanation of its internal representation.

**I want to know what kind of packets I can send to server and clients and how they are built, their structure and such?**

I already know how to download and upload files to the net over sockets, so I think I should be able to handle torrent files too.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: The BitTorrent protocol is described in detail here: http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification.  See also [this Google search.](http://www.google.com/#q=torrent+protocol)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking a look at some source code of other clients?

Check out [this GIT Repo](http://git.deluge-torrent.org/deluge/)

Torrent clients aren't easy to build, and explaining them in a post would be difficult. Do plenty of research, Google is your friend!